# How to get the text from one ui forms QTextEdit widget to the MainWindow C++ file

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to save the text input from a QTextEdit widget on a ui form i created called myTabPage. This ui was created separately from the MainWindow ui because I needed textedits to be dynamically added to the MainWindows tabwidget as new tabs are created. Each tab is a new file or loaded file the user can edit. I'm looking to get the text from the QTabWidget widget in the mytabpage ui from the MainWindow.cpp file so that it can be added to a new file to be saved in a user-chosen dir.

Right now, I am trying to create a new pointer to the mytabpage.cpp class in an action handler for the save button that is supposed to open with the layout of the current tab,

```
QWidget *curw = ui->mytab->currentWidget();
myTabPage *savepage = new myTabPage(curw);
QString savstr = savepage->getInText();
```

mytab is located on the MainWindow and is the encapsulating widget for the mytabpage ui form. `getInText()` is a function I made in the `mytabpage` c++ file to send back the plain text of the `qtabwidget`

```
QString myTabPage::getInText(){
    QString str = ui->input->toPlainText();
    return str;
}
```

and I have the constructor for mytabpage.cpp setup like this

```
myTabPage::myTabPage(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::myTabPage)
{
    if(parent != nullptr){
        ui->setupUi(parent);
    }else{
        ui->setupUi(this);
    }
}
```

unfortunately this only leads to an output error

```
QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to myTabPage "myTabPage", which already has a layout
```

and everytime I run it, the toPlainText() function always comes back empty.

I have tried connections with signals and slots but everytime I run I get a crash, these are the connections

```
//connect(ui->input, SIGNAL(textChanged()), this, SLOT(on_input_TextChanged()));
//connect(ui->output, SIGNAL(textChanged()), this, SLOT(on_output_TextChanged()));
```

and I added on_click() functions to go along with those connections

```
void myTabPage::on_input_TextChanged(){
    inText.append(ui->input->toPlainText());
}

void myTabPage::on_output_TextChanged(){
    outText.append(ui->output->toPlainText());
}
```

I have also tried creating global variables for the mytabpage c++ file to store the text from each textedit everytime one of the textedits text changes, with the help of the connections above.

Just the beginning of my `on_actionSave_triggered()` func

```
void MainWindow::on_actionSave_triggered(){
    QWidget *curw = ui->mytab->currentWidget();
    myTabPage *savepage = new myTabPage(curw);
    QString savstr = savepage->getInText();
    int curi = ui->mytab->currentIndex();
    QString fn = ui->mytab->tabText(curi);
    //debug shit
    qDebug() << curw;
    qDebug() << savepage->getInText();
    QTextEdit *txt = savepage->retIn();
    qDebug() << txt->toPlainText();
    qDebug() << "hello";
    //savepage->setOutText(savstr);
    //
```

Everything else inside this function has to do with opening a dialog box to select a place to save the file.

**---------------------EDIT--------------------------------------------------**

To answer @drescherjm second reply,

```
qDebug() << ui->output;
```

is a debug line I used in the mytabpage.cpp in the constructor to see if it exists, the result is the console output `QWidget(0x0)`. The way the window is laid out, the input textedit should be 0x0, and the output textedit should be 1x0. unless thats a hex code im misreferencing. Either way, when I try

```
qDebug() << ui->input;
```

the program crashes, this is the output

```
17:22:28: The program has unexpectedly finished.
17:22:28: The process was ended forcefully.
```

Comment: ***How to get the text from one ui forms QTextEdit widget to the MainWindow C++ file*** With Qt using signals and slots is a good choice for this.

Comment: ***I have tried connections with signals and slots but everytime I run I get a crash, these are the connections*** My recommendation is to use a debugger to figure out why. I don't see why in the code that is presented.

Comment: To answer @drescherjm I added an edit to the post above to answer your second reply